# Php backend fundamental threading

Tags: php, backend, rpc

I have a php-backend. Lets say two users send rpc to the server. My entrypoint is service.php. 
service.php contains a class `Service` with some functions. 
service.php calls the function from the Class/Object from service. I write **or**, cause I'm not sure how to structure php-backends. This leads to my question.

questions:

Do the rpc get resolved like this (non-threading): rpc from user1 is completely done. rpc from user2 is completely done.

Or is it like this (threading): rpc from user1 is being processed. rpc from user2 is being processed while rpc from user1 is still processed.

So can it be if I use only static variables and objects, that the rpc from user2 changes static-varaibles while rpc from user1 is being processed?

Comment: Both requests can be processed concurrently (setup dependent?). Statics are not shared resources between requests.

Comment: does every rpc has it's own environment? So is it possible to change a variable that is not super-global?

Comment: No PHP variable changes you make in one request will affect the other requets, super-global or not.

Comment: can you please explain in more detail, I'm very interested and I'm not sure if my 3 questions are answered

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the time or deep knowledge to give you a detailed explanation. Maybe somebody else can.